# Is it possible in entity framework to have a constant string as a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want the join to be on an id (real column) and comment type (string). The following example doesn't work but should indicate my intention.

```cs
public class Something
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    // Does this have to be in the database?
    public string CommentType = "Something-type-comment";

    [ForeignKey("CommentRecordId,CommentType")]
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public long CommentRecordId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order=2)]
    public string CommentType { get; set; }   
}
```

When this gets converted to sql I'd like it to translate to something like the following.

```
SELECT * from Something s 
    JOIN Comment c ON 
        s.Id = c.CommentRecordId 
            and
        c.CommentType = 'Something-type-comment'; --there is no corresponding field in Something table
```

EDIT:
Also by the way, when I try it this way I get the following error.
"The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical."

Comment: What is the question? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the title is the question. "Is it possible in entity framework to have a string as a foreign key?"

Comment: Also the comment above the property CommentType should show in the example what I'm asking

Comment: How is the database supposed to have a foreign key based on data that's not in the database?

Comment: BTW I think you mean "constant" string instead of "static" string.  `static` has a specific meaning in C# that's different that how you are using it.

Comment: constant it is. - I'll clarify my intent on the foreign key but not in the database in the question

Comment: That SQL statement makes no sense... are you saying Something.Id == CommentType.Id && Something.Type == CommentType.Type

Comment: No, Something.Type is a non-existent field in the database so I'd like that to be a string. The sql query does work perfectly fine when i run it.

Comment: Ok I see what's happened

Comment: Did you check enums and lookup tables for it? Looks like it might really fit you, if you can change property type from string to enum. Sadly, DB calls will still introduce foreign key as an inteher

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to do what you want *AND* make it a foreign key.  There is no construct in SQL that allows a constant value to be part of a foreign key.  You can use other constructs like a computed column, CHECK constraint or triggers to ensure that the underlying data data is "constant" but the foreign key has to reference table columns.  These methods, however, cannot be configured using code first that I am aware of, so you'll have to configure those at the database level.

If you have to have a foreign key then I would suggest persisting the column in the database and making it a true foreign key, perhaps using business rules or one of the methods above.

A second option is to remove the foreign key attributes and just enforce the relationship (and the constant value) through business rules.  (i.e. embed the constant value in your repository queries so that the equivalent SQL you specify is generated).

Something like

```
var query = from s in Something
            join c in Comment
            on new {s.Id, CommentType = "Something-type-comment"} equals 
               new {c.CommentRecordId, c.CommentType}
            select new {s, c}
```

or

```
var query = from s in Something
            join c in Comment
            on s.Id equals c.CommentRecordId
            where c.CommentType == "Something-type-comment" 
            select new {s, c}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second option?

Comment: @matthewdaniel I have updated the question with a few options